# Number validation for JavaScript simple calculator with RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, numeric

I am making a simple calculator with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The input field must be validated with regex to accept only numbers and the mathematical signs + - * / .

This is the input field in the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer-field" oninput="checking()" />
```

And this is the JavaScript function checking():

```
function checking(){
  var x = document.calculator.answer.value;  // the value of the input field
  var regex=/[0-9]\b/;  // my failing regex 
    if (x.match(regex) || (x==="+") || (x==="-") || (x==="*") || (x==="/"))
    {
      document.getElementById("problemWithInputMessage").innerHTML="";
      console.log("true, it IS a number");
      return true;
    }
    else if(!(x.match(regex))){
      console.log("false, not a number");
      document.getElementById("problemWithInputMessage").innerHTML="You can only input numbers and the following signs + - * /";
      x = x.substring(0, x.length - 1);   // removing the wrong symbol
      document.calculator.answer.value = x;
      return false;
    }
}
```

The problems are several. For starters, the regular expression is not working properly, because it only searches at the beginnings and endings of the input string. Also, some signs, different than +-*/. do stay inside the input field and don't get excluded.

Can you help me to validate the input field properly for numbers and the signs +-*/. only?

Comment: probably it's that "word boundary" `\b` in there, shouldn't it just be `[0-9]+` to detect (one or more) numbers?

Comment: No, it doesn't work at all. I tried adding + and then I tried +$, although I don't rly get it, instead of \b but the problem remains. Only difference is that now it won't accept any signs, not even the ones I need +-*/.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up submitting this code:

```
function checking() {
  var x = document.calculator.answer.value;
  document.getElementById("problemWithInputMessage").innerHTML="";
    var regexNumbers = /[0-9]+$/;                       //Regular Expression for the numbers
    var regexSigns = new RegExp(/[\+\-\/\*]+$/g);       //Regular Expression for the Special Signs

    if(x.match(regexSigns) || x.match(regexNumbers)) {  //checking for Numbers and the Special allowed signs
        return true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("problemWithInputMessage").innerHTML="You can only input numbers and the following signs + - * /";
      x = x.substring(0, x.length - 1); //Deleting the last symbol if it is not allowed
      document.calculator.answer.value = x;
      return false;
    }
}
```

I separated the 2 tasks in 2 different Regular Expressions. The first one

> /[0-9]+$/

checks for numbers only, and the second one

> /[+-/*]+$/g

checks for the special symbols +-/* (although I forgot to put in the dot .) Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot :)

It is not 100%-proofed because if you type at the back of the string it is all ok, but if you put the cursor inside a string of numbers you entered, it will still allow you to enter letters and other symbols in the middle.